# Space shuttle TVC hydraulic line diameter?

Tags: space-shuttle, thrust-vectoring

Curious what diameter the hydraulic lines of the space shuttle thrust vector control system might have been. Even a ballpark figure would be OK. Is this info by chance public?

Comment: I'll see if I can find something public tomorrow.  I'm sure there is at least a picture somewhere.'

Comment: Awesome---thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an approximate answer.

This is the right Space Shuttle Main Engine (SSME) mounting "hole" on Orbiter OV-104 (Atlantis). The yellow cylinders sticking out are covers over the shafts of the Thrust Vector Control actuators.

[image]

(Personal photo)

Zooming in, we can see the hydraulic lines to/from the pitch actuator as well as the bolt circle for the gimbal bearing.

[image]

The [SSME Orientation](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf) p.10 says the gimbal bearing is about a foot wide.  So the hydraulic lines are around an inch in diameter, roughly speaking.

Comment: Wow! That's a nice close-up of the engine bay! Yeah, 1-in minimum on the line diameter, it seems. Maybe even 2-in? They're wider that I thought they'd be.

Comment: Now curious: what type of joint went between the TVC cylinders and the frame? It seems it wouldn't have been a simple hinge with just one rotational degree of freedom, as the cylinders would each need to move with the nozzle, which would generally be rotating about two axes... So at minimum you would need a hinge with two rotational degrees of freedom... e.g., like a universal joint? Or a ball joint? And what about the joint between the TVC cylinders and the nozzle? Simple hinge there wouldn't be enough, but a ball joint at each end would allow the shaft to rotate unconstrained about its axis?

Comment: OK, I take back what I said about the joint at the nozzle end. It seems that a universal joint (or equivalent) with two rotational degrees of freedom on the *frame* side plus a simple hinge with one rotational degree of freedom on the *nozzle* side would be just right? (Or alternatively one universal-like joint on the nozzle side and one simple hinge on the frame side?)

Comment: Looks like a clevis type joint on both ends https://imgur.com/mvBhRtv  The frame one may be a ball joint (probably is).

Comment: OK so it looks like the frame-side is a hinge on a ball joint which would give it three rotation degrees of freedom on that side... And it also looks like a hinge on a ball joint on the nozzle side, which would give it three rotational degrees of freedom there... which would mean the cylinder is free to rotate unconstrained about its long axis... which would be a problem as it would be constantly hitting hard stops on both sides? Hinge on a ball seems OK if it's only on one side, with the other side being a simple hinge without the ball to fully constrain the cylinder and stop unwanted motion.

Comment: Thanks for the schematic!

Comment: Better diagrams in here https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19840002116/downloads/19840002116.pdf p.24 Looking there it does look like a ball joint on the vehicle side and a hinge on the engine side.  That's for the SRB but probably essentially the same if not exactly the same.

Comment: No way! This exists! OK new pet project, model space shuttle TVC hydraulics :D

Comment: Here's an engine mount point with the TVC actuators out, does look like a pin holds them on. https://imgur.com/YQv6whs

Comment: This paper is good too. Both ends may be balls. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20120014513/downloads/20120014513.pdf  In fact, if you look at the ppt included at the end, you can see that they are (page 17 of the pdf).  So that's my final comment-answer, lol.

Comment: Oh yeah, they are! And the first picture shows the frame-side hinge is cupped to support the cylinder end as it "yaws" or "rolls". So OK, ball joints on both ends would accommodate slight misalignments (e.g., due to manufacturing tolerances, etc), which would be good. But... only one rotational degree of freedom is actively controlled, with a second being fully constrained by the motion of the second cylinder... leaving the third rotational degree of freedom fully unconstrained... and that would be "roll" about the cylinder's axis, which oscillate side to side, possibly causing vibration?

Comment: Not sure if that vibration could excite the bending modes of the shuttle, but those bending modes were clearly important in the design of the shuttle frame and the control algorithms---with those bending filters added to the control algorithms just to protect against those bending modes... so it seems strange that the TVC cylinders would be underconstrained and free to roll against the clevis stops. The ball joints must have at least been heavily damped.

Comment: OK, so the PPT slides show the hydraulic lines more clearly, and it seems they must be closer to 1/2 in.